# Git merge overwrites all changes

Tags: git, git-flow

I have two branches: A and B
I would like to merge other person changes made on branch B to my local branch A, but i would like to pick which changes safe (i would like to apply some from other branch and some from my made on my branch).

I was trying:

```
git merge B
```

command with differents sets of options like --no-ff, -X theirs/ours etc. but every strategy overwrites every changes i made on my branch (A).

Comment: Maybe try going to branch B and merging in your changes from branch A.  Maybe make a new branch C (when in B) to try that out.

Comment: Also try pushing your branch to remote first, maybe the issue is arround staging vs index etc

Comment: The way to "dry-run" a merge is `--no-ff --no-commit`. The merge will construct the merge commit in the staging area and stop, so you can use `git status` and `git diff --cached` and all the other normal ways of "looking around" to see what you've "done".

Comment: no --no-ff --no-commit doesn't work

Comment: can you be more specific? you want to take only a few patches from a branch, and some few other from another branch, and so on? do you need to merge those branches in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `--no-commit` option to have a chance to review the merge before creating it :

```
git merge --no-commit
# review changes ...
# once you are satisfied with the content :
git commit    # this will create the merge commit
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to apply a specific commit from branch B on top of your changes from branch A, here's a simple way to do it:

```
git checkout A
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

where  is the hexadecimal string identifier for the commit you want to apply. You can find these hashes by looking at the git log on branch B:

```
git checkout B
git log
```

Keep in mind however that this doesn't merge branch B into branch A. Branch B will remain as it is after being cherry-picked from. If you'd like to apply *all* changes from branch B on top of branch A while getting rid of branch B, try doing a git rebase:

```
git checkout A
git rebase B
```

what this does is replay the entire commit history of branch B on top of branch A, making them essentially one branch.